# i am not able to locate "Add to wishlist" web element on the quick view of the image

Tags: selenium, automation

Here in this code, I am not able to locate the "Add to wishlist" web element on the quick view of the image.

[Add To Wishlist Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcM1k.png)

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php");  
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='block_top_menu']/ul/li[2]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='categories_block_left']/div/ul/li[3]/a")).click(); driver.findElement(By.id("list")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='center_column']/ul/li1/div/div/div/div")).click();  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[contains(@class,'box-cart-bottom')]//[contains(@id,'wishlist_button')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the picture there is an iframe there, so you need to switch to it first and only after that access the elements inside it.
To get the right, clear and unique locator of that iframe we need to se the entire page HTML.
Once you have iframe locator switching to it can be done with:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
```

or any other relevant locator